# How to overwrite default detekt.yml?

Tags: kotlin, detekt

Is there a way to overwrite only a few config properties for detekt, and preserve most props from `default-detekt-config.yml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is!

I assume you are using the `gradle-plugin`. Actually you can specify more than one config file in the `config` property:

```
gradle
detekt {
    defaultProfile {
        ...
        # config = "path/to/default.yml, path/to/my/config.yml"
        config = files(file("default-config"), file("my-config"))
    }
}
```

The config property can be a FileCollection, a File or just a String with comma-separated path entries.
Make sure that the default configuration file is listed first.
Now you can override each rule setting and property in your custom detekt configuration file.

Take a look how we @detekt configure two configs here https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt/blob/master/build.gradle.kts#L206 and this is how our custom config file looks like: https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt/blob/master/reports/failfast.yml.

Edit: If you are using just the CLI, you may write java -jar detekt.jar --config "first-config.yml,second-config.yml" ....

Comment: Is there any way just to overwrite one property? e.g. via simple variables in gradle?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The yaml file is the only place where rules get configured.
However with https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt/pull/1417 merged in the next version, you will be able to just override the properties you want without copy-pasting the whole default configuration file.

Comment: hoorray, it works! Thank you so much for pull 1417 :-)

Comment: maybe you can provide a new (official) answer in this thread?